# Removing duplicate keys/values from tuple-list

Tags: list, haskell, key, tuples

I have a list of tuples, `(key,value)` pairs. I need to remove elements that duplicate the key or the value, order of the list can change, but the first occurrence of the key or the value must remain in the list of tuples:

Example:

```
input: [("r","w"),("n","j"),("a","j"),("d","i"),("s","g"),("r","a")]
output: [("r","w"),("n","j"),("d","i"),("s","g")]
```

What I made:

```
removeDuplicates  _   []  = []
removeDuplicates seen (x:xs) 
                        | elem (head $ fst x) (fst seen) = [] ++ removeDuplicates seen xs
                        | elem (head $ snd x) (snd seen) = [] ++ removeDuplicates seen xs
                        | otherwise  = x:removeDuplicates ((fst seen)++(fst x),(snd seen)++(snd x)) xs
```

But this needs to be called as `removeDuplicates ("","") something` which is ugly.

Comment: What have you already tried, what error are you getting

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I have added my solution, but it's pretty ugly in my opinion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the [`nubBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy) function from the `Data.List` package with the appropriate comparator:

```
removeDuplicates xs = nubBy cmpKeyAndVal xs 
  where
    cmpKeyAndVal (x, y) (x', y') = x == x' || y == y'
```

Used as:

```
> removeDuplicates [("r","w"),("n","j"),("a","j"),("d","i"),("s","g"),("r","a")]
[("r","w"),("n","j"),("d","i"),("s","g")]
```

Also note that calling your implementation with `("", "")` yields incorrect results when either a key or value is `""`. The only way to choose a correct first argument is to put something that doesn't appear in the input, which is a bit annoying to do.

---

Note that the above implementation takes O(n^2) time, which is optimal for `Eq` instances. If you can allow an `Ord` constraint you can use the [`sortBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) function which implements a *stable* sorting algorithm, and then use `groupBy` to remove the contiguous duplicates:

```
import Data.List(sortBy, groupBy)
import Data.Ord(comparing)
import Data.Function(on)

removeDuplicates xs = sortAndGroupBy snd (sortAndGroupBy fst xs)
  where
    sortAndGroupBy f = map head . groupBy ((==) `on` f). sortBy (comparing f)
```

This takes O(nlog n) time instead, but obviously require an `Ord` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, get in the habit of adding a type-signature when writing a function. It keeps you sane and honest, it captures what you want to do, and is best written before you implement your function.

```
removeDuplicates :: (Eq a, Eq a1) => ([a], [a1]) -> [([a], [a1])] -> [([a], [a1])]
```

If you want to have it being called without the additional parameter, I would propose something like this:

```
remove :: (Eq a, Eq a1) => [([a], [a1])] -> [([a], [a1])]
remove = removeDuplicates ("","")
```

Another more general version which would not work only with lists as elements of your tuples, would be this:

```
removeX :: (Eq t, Eq s) => [(t, s)] -> [(t, s)]
removeX [] = []
removeX (xx@(x,y):xs) = let xs' = filter (\(a,b) -> not (a == x || b ==y) ) xs
                        in xx:removeX xs'
```

If you want to stick with standard functions - @Bakuriu has the right answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Put the accumulator in a helper function.

```
removeDuplicates lst = rd lst []
                       where rd _ [] = []
                             rd seen (x:xs) = ...
```